# how to select rows with comma and single quotes string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT student.className)
  FROM student
 WHERE student.studentId in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

this example select class names as `1B,1F,2F,3F`

but, i want to select row with single quotes and comma like,

```
 '1B','1F','2F','3F'
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

save this query in variable and fetch using while loop
and save data in variable and print using echo json_encode(variable)